# What is the indefinite integral of ln(ln(lnx))?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the indefinite integral of $\ln(\ln(\ln(x))$?
I came across this question somewhere and got curious as to what would be the solution. I know that the indefinite integral of $\ln(\ln(x))$ is $x \ln(\ln(x))-\operatorname{li}(x)+C$ and am familiar with introductory college level calculus. Do we have to use another special function?

Comment: I don(t think that, even using special functions, we could get an expression for this integral.

Comment: Heard of [horseshoe mathematics](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=j4hW7AwETZA)? The solution to this integral is *itself*. :~)

Comment: This is what Wolfram Alpha is born to do! Anyways, no solutions...